# .NET core - Configure JWT Authentication at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 Web Application and I am using the **[Authorize]** attribute on the controllers that require authentication. As authentication mechanism, I am using `JWT` which I could configure in the `Startup` class using

```
.AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.Audience = "....";
    options.Authority = "....";
});
```

This would work great. My problem is that I don't have the information for audience and authority at startup and **I need to configure this at runtime.**

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't know whether is there a way or not to do what you are asking but... once the *Startup* class has executed  *ConfigureServices* and  *Configure* methods your Web Application will be Up&Running and ready to receive requests. 
So, when would you know this information about *audience and authority*?

Comment: Basically the first user accessing the web application will do a setup. The information about audience and authority will be known at some point at runtime when this user calls a public route, which is also when I want to try and reconfigure the authentication.

Comment: @NuhRuqa give a look to this example https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/tree/master/samples/DynamicSchemes

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

1. Register multi jwt authentication schema and dynamically choose the needed schema based on parameter/reqeust header value in request . Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55062246/5751404) for code sample .
2. Config and replace your ISecurityTokenValidator. Use DI to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to read data from request .Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57472245/5751404) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57727839/5751404) for code sample .
3. Manually validating a JWT token with `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` . Click [here](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/manually-validating-rs256-jwt-dotnet/) for code sample .

Answer (score 0):

It is worth understanding the extensibility points also, since Microsoft provide a customizable framework. Some people (including myself) prefer a library based approach to dealing with JWTs.

This is possible via a [CustomAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/security/CustomAuthenticationHandler.cs), and its implementation can use a JWT library. My code example uses [jose-jwt](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt) via [this handler class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.cs#L38).

This enables you to validate JWTs however you like and take closer control over behaviour. Hopefully it provides an idea or two for your own solution. Further details in this [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/06/net-core-oauth-coding/).